# Changing a pendant light to an LED pendant ligh

Tags: wiring

I am installing 3 LED pendant lights where regular pendant lights  were previously from the new LED light there are 2 wires silver clear coated and a silver clear coated with a white stripe. From the ceiling there is a white wire, a black wire, 2 bare copper wires and a braided copper mesh wire.  How do I wire it?

Comment: Can you please provide pictures?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 silver wires are connected to the black wire, the two silver wires w/ a white strip are connected to the white wire, all of the bare wires are connected to your bare wire in the box.